# Android, pop up a message on exception

Tags: android, exception

I have an android app connected to a servlet. If the servlet is down (happened to me yesterday) the app crashes. I need to pop up a message to the user informing about some connection issues and then terminate the application.

on onCreate() method, i call an AsyncTask class, in which is done the first connection to the server. I have a try/catch(UnknownHostException e) block, which is activated if the sevlet is down.
The problem is that i cant create a pop up message there. I tried toast and AllertDialogs, but both return an exception

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Is there some other way i can do this? Thanks in advance, ilias

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean and read it after the function call, at which point you should be able to show a toast/dialog. But that's hard to say without the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `AsyncTask` is running in a background thread. Calls to show a `Toast` or a `Dialog` must be made on the main (UI) thread. To do this from within an `AsyncTask` you can do this:

You'll need an activity context in your `AsyncTask`, so have your activity create your `AsyncTask` like this:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask(this, ...); // pass "this" so AsyncTask has an activity context
```

In your `AsyncTask` constructor, save the activity context so you can use it later:

```
private Activity activity;

// Constructor
MyAsyncTask(Activity activity, ...) {
    this.activity = activity;
    ...
}
```

When you want to show a Dialog or a Toast, make sure the code runs on the main (UI) thread:

```
// Here we want to Toast
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do your Toast or Dialog stuff in here
            ...        
        }
 });
```

Comment: I shouldn't call toast on AsyncTask, or i must not!? I figured an other way, the asynctask was returning a string. within catch i returned a value of -1, so on postexecute i check if it is -1 and then pop up the message